# Weird characters though using the right encoding

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8

I work on a website that has different language interfaces, so far I use english and german.

when the german text is loaded, it shows weird characters like the following screenshot

[image]

though I use

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and also in the html header

```
<META http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

what else can I do to solve it ?

Thanks

Comment: You've shown what you're using for *output* encoding - but you haven't told us anything about how you're *loading* the text in the first place. I strongly suspect that that's the problem.

Comment: I have 12 reputation, which doesnt give me the right to accept answers, what should I do about that ?

Comment: Go into your profile, find your questions and accept some answers.

Comment: whenever i try to, a popup tells me that i should have 15 reputation to accept answers!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of the page needs to also be in UTF-8. Your content was probably made using MS Word, which uses Windows 1251 encoding. You need to re-save your document as UTF-8.

UTF-8 does not convert formats for you.

Comment: some of the content comes from csv files, does those get saved in any specific encoding ?

Comment: Yes, they probably came from Excel or MS Access, both of which have a "save as UTF-8" option in the 2010 version. You will need to re-save these documents.

Comment: okay I get it now, thanks a lot, when I get enough reputation I promise to accept this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If those strings are saved in a file, the file has to be encoded in UTF-8 too.
If you're getting them from a database, they'll have to be stored as UTF-8 and you'll have to set the connection charset to utf-8.

You could also check whether your text is UTF-8 and if not, convert it with utf8_encode.